# Creating a normal form of a database

Tags: mysql-workbench

My job is to do the database of our website. I have to do the normal form of it, but that's where I'm stuck.

If you have time to help me with it, please write me back so I can send you the database file.

Comment: Please explain your use case and ask questions around it.

Comment: @notionquest To be more specifically, I have the DB almost done. But i have to do the DB - Design of it. I have to connect those tables in a way that there will be data redundancy.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. To ask a question here, (a) work out exactly what your problem is, (b) research it thoroughly first, (c) ask a complete and self-contained question. This site is not for advertising for private one-to-one help. Please show your whole problem in the question itself; you can expect it to be put on hold for now.